# ORM - Many to Many vs belongs with properties of Model

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I am using Laravel's ORM model (eloquent), yet this doesn't relate only to Laravel.

I have a Recipe model and I would like to manipulate data on any other model that relates to Recipe, i.e. vitamins, product type, etc (in each recipe). At first I thought it's classic `belongsTo` Recipe. Yet if, from the vitamins table, each `Vitamin` shows the range of volume it exists in each Recipe. By this design, doesn't this mean that this relationship is `ManyToMany`?

Thanks, Bud

Comment: Yes. It is many to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To think of [`"one-to-many" relationship`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), it defines a single model **has many** other models. For example, a user can create many recipes. We can say a user **has many** recipes and a recipe **belongs to** a user only (but not **share with** other users).

And [`"many-to-many" relationship`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), for example of a relation with recipe with many vitamins, where the vitamins are also **shared by** other recipes. So we can say a recipe **belongs to many** vitamins, and a vitamin **belongs to many** recipe.